# Using Javascript / JQuery to check how how many hours to a date time field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently am in a situation, where I have direct user input formulating a datetime using a datetime picker. It produces output in this format:

```
24-May-2018 05:45pm
```

Using JavaScript, what is the best way to determine if the selected time is at least **3 hours ahead** of the current datetime.

Comment: If you're using jQuery-UI Datepicker, you can get the value as a `Date` object using the `getDate` method. Then you can simply subtract the time from the current time.

Comment: If you are going to be doing a lot with datetime objects, you can add [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). It's 16kb

Answer (score 2):

I would say, use `moment.js`.

```
moment('24-May-2018 05:45pm', 'DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mmA') > moment().add(3, 'hour')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript, the simplest way would be to directly subtract the date objects from one another.

For example:

```
var hours = Math.abs(userInputtedDate - Date.now()) / (60 * 60 * 10000);

if (hours < 3) { 
    //do something
}
```

The subtraction returns the difference between the two dates in milliseconds. The division converts those milliseconds into hours.